# maskoceans with no ocean in mask and no data

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib-basemap

I would like to plot the surface elevation of Antarctica from netcdf files I have, but masking the ocean. Therfore, I used "maskoceans". However, when using it, everthing is white. If I look at the created mask, it is written "True" everywhere, so it did not recognize the surface of oceans. Moreover, the created array associated to the land/ocean mask is empty. I do not understand what is happening. I have tried with other basemap projections, but the problem is still the same. I also use the projected coordinates.

I made tests with drawlsmask:

1. Without using maskoceans, just the blank space at lon=180° (another problem I have!) is fulled with the specified colors.
2. Using maskoceans, it correctly full the land and the ocean.

Finally, one last problem I have is that a bland space (a line) at lon=180° remains.

I hope someone will be able to help me and thank in advance those who will try to.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import cdms2 as cdms
import cdtime

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap,shiftgrid,maskoceans

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

##################################################

path='/home/dryas/Sentia/data_ECHAM/T106.surf_height.nc'
var='geosp'

tstart=cdtime.comptime(1960,1,1,0,1,0)
tstop=cdtime.comptime(2013,1,1,23,59)

#Extraction
f=cdms.open(path)
var=f(var)
f.close

lat=var.getLatitude() 
lon=var.getLongitude()

timax=var.getTime()
timax.getBounds()
timax.asComponentTime()
var=var(time=(tstart,tstop))
var=var[0,:,:]
var=var.filled()

#Map
fig=plt.figure()

m=Basemap(projection='spstere',boundinglat=-60,lon_0=-180,resolution='l')

lons,lats=np.meshgrid(lon,lat)
x,y=m(lons,lats)

mdata=maskoceans(x,y,var,resolution='h',grid=1.25,inlands=True)
cs=m.contourf(x,y,mdata)

cbar=m.colorbar(cs,location='right')
cbar.set_label('surface elevation (m)')

m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawmapboundary()

m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,90.,10.),labels=[1,0,0,0],fontsize=10)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180,180,30.),labels=[0,0,0,1],fontsize=10)

plt.title('Surface Elevation')
plt.show()
```

[image: Map without using "maskoceans"]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have managed to full the blank space at 180°:

```
var=f(var,longitude=(0,360,'cc'))
```

However I still cannot mask the ocean :(

Anyone to help?

Sentia

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem with maskoceans:

I had put the x,y coordinates in maskoceans instead of the lats lons ones. Now it works =)